# Can't save macro-enabled workbook on remote server after a macro has run

Tags: excel, vba

My macro-enabled workbook has been working fine until recently. It runs fine on my local drive, but no longer saves itself when run from a remote folder. I suspect some recent updates on the server are to blame.

If I open the workbook and press the save button, a pop-up appears with a progress bar for a second or two. This has not happened before, but the pop-up does close and allow me to continue.

When I run the macro in the workbook, the last line is ThisWorkbook.Save. The same pop-up appears and hangs. If I close the pop-up and press the save button, it also hangs now. If I choose File> SaveAs, all I get is a blank page with no folders to choose from.

I have a workaround to copy the workbook to a local folder, run the macro, then copy it back to the remote drive, but this may be difficult for my users to handle.

I made a new workbook with a macro that only calls ThisWorkbook.Save from a single button, and this works fine. The problematic workbook gets data from csv files and copies it into itself. Maybe this is causing a problem? Maybe the macros are too large for the anti-malware software to handle?

Does anyone know what recent changes have been made to Server that would cause my old macro to hang on saving?

Answer (score 0):

I got the macro working, but not sure why.

The problem arose with an inefficient way to merge data from two sheets together. I had been using Find, and changed it to march through the data row by row instead. The saving window still pops up, but only for a second.

I don't know exactly why the old method prevented the workbook from being saved. The main difference is that the Find method uses objects, while the method I changed it to use integers and compare cell contents with an if statement. Maybe the memory was being filled with orphaned objects? I don't see what difference that should make when saving the file. The data in the sheets being saved is the same.

If anyone knows what difference this would make in saving a workbook, please add and answer or comment for posterity. It might help someone with a similar problem.